# How can I add jQuery DateTimePicker to my project in visual studio

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquerydatetimepicker

I have a requirement where I need the following control in my project. I am using MVC application in this project.

https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker

But, I am totally unsure how I can use this control in my project, as I am doing this for the first time. I did followed the steps that they have given. I installed those packages in one of my local folder. But this folder is different location and the project I am using is in different location. Should I install this package in the location of my project where I am using this? Please someone help me with this.

Comment: In the Visual Studio go to `Tools ► NuGet Package Manager  ► Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...` and add the `jQuery-datetimepicker` package to your project.

Comment: When you use the `NuGet Packages Manager` it will install the required package under the `packages` folder in the solution directory.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't show up any results under the browse tab.

Comment: Did you type the `jQuery-datetimepicker` package name?

Comment: Yes. I navigated to tools-> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution - Browse - jQuery-datetimepicker. This gives no results

Comment: Then go to `Tools ► Options...`. Click on `Package Sources` under `NuGet Package Manager` and check that `Available package sources:` is set. It should be set to `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`. So the **NuGet Package Manager** will use this source to obtain list of available packages.

Comment: I couldn't see Available Package sources option. All I could see is the package source, which is referring to my project git branch. I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: It's okay. In VS2019 it is `Package Sources:`; in the VS2017 is `Available package sources:`. Does the `Package sources:` set to the `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` and _checked_?

Comment: No. It is set to /nuget/v3/index.json which is to the project repo that I am working on.

Comment: This is the problem. Change it to `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`.

Comment: Great! I was now able to install it. Thankyou so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:** To add the <kbd>jQuery DateTimePicker</kbd> package to a project:

1. In the *Visual Studio* go to `Tools ► NuGet Package Manager ► Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...`.
2. Click on the `Browse` tab. Type the `jQuery-datetimepicker` package name and wait until the available packages list is populated.
3. Then select the `jQuery-datetimepicker` package, check project(s) the package to be installed and press <kbd>Install</kbd> button. Wait while the package is installing.

**Step 2:** In case the available packages list does not updated do the following:

1. In the Visual Studio go to `Tools ► Options...`. In the `Options` dialog find out `Package Sources` under `NuGet Package Manager` and check that `Package sources` is set to `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`. So the NuGet Package Manager will use this source to obtain list of available packages:

[image]

2. Perform *Step 1)*.

> For additional information see [Install and manage packages in Visual
> Studio using the NuGet Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(VS.ToolsOptionsPages.NuGet_Package_Manager.Package_Sources)%26rd%3Dtrue)